# Bad Gateway from nginx published with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I am learning docker-compose and now I am trying to setup app and nginx in one docker-compose script on my WSL Ubuntu.
I am testing my endpoint with

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1/weatherforecast
```

But I am receiving 502 Bad Gateway from nginx.
If I change port exposing to port publishing in docker-compose, as below, requests bypass nginx and reach my app and I receive an expected response.

```
ports:
   - 5000:8080
```

My setup:
**app's dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication2.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    build: ./WebApplication2    
    expose:
      - "8080"
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

**>docker-compose ps**

```
       Name                      Command               State                Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
composetest_nginx_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp
composetest_web_1     dotnet WebApplication2.dll       Up      8080/tcp
```

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
[error] 31#31: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.26.0.1, server: , request: "GET /weatherforecast HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/weatherforecast", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

cURL output:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /weatherforecast HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: nginx/1.21.1
< Date: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 17:50:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 157
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.1</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect your request to your `web` container instead of `127.0.0.1`. Each container is running as separate part of network (each has different IP address) and `127.0.0.1` points to local container. So, in your case, it point to `nginx` itself. Instead of real IP address of container, you can use DNS name (it is equal to service name in `docker-compose`). Use something like:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8080/;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you specified that your `web` container depends on `nginx`, but it should be viceversa. Like:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
```